# Analogue for maven-resources-plugin or maven-antrun-plugin for leiningen

Tags: build, clojure, leiningen

I use leiningen to manage my clojure project and I want to copy jar file along with some other files into a certain directory as a final part of a build process. Leiningen treats 'resources' as something which should be included into the jar file, and it is unacceptable for me. If I used maven, I could configure it for such task using maven-resource-plugin or fall back to Ant using maven-antrun-plugin, but leiningen is far more convenient tool for clojure projects.

Strangely, I couldn't manage to find anything about similar functionality in leiningen on the internet. This is curious, because one of major clojure applications is web sites, and web sites usually do not include their resources (js, css, etc) into the jar (or do they? That would be weird since slight css tweak will require rather lenghty recompilation). It comes naturally that we have to prepare site environment (copy static resources along with jar bundle into some directory layout), and this task should be done by the build tool.

Is there a plugin to copy files around the filesystem (or something which could substitute it, like running Ant), or I must write one myself? Right now I'm using shell scripts, but it is very inconvenient since I had to run several commands instead of one, and also it is unportable.

Comment: Well, I wrote now an Ant wrapper around some lein commands and file management, but still this doesn't feel good. Maybe the reason of the lack of such features is that leiningen architecture differs from maven one (no explicit phases of project build to which plugins are attached), but, whatever. Ant solution satisfies me enough.

Answer (score 2):

did you checkout [lein-resource](https://github.com/m0smith/lein-resource)?
in any case. here is a long list of [available plugins](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins) for lein, maybe you will fine some of them helpful

Comment: I had asked my question half a year before initial commit of `lein-resource` :) Nothing comparable to it was available then. But still, it seems to be less powerful than `maven-resources-plugin`.

Comment: right :) i thought it would be nice to link the plugins here, in case someone looks for something like this in the future

Comment: As the writer of lein-resource, it is intended to be the same as the maven resource plugin.  It does what I need so I have not touched it in a while.  If there is some missing functionality, let me know.